# PHP Warning: Module 'gd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, composer-php, codeigniter-4

How do I fix `PHP Warning: Module 'gd' is already loaded in Unknown on line 0`?

I am using PHP, Composer and CodeIgniter 4.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code that triggers this warning

Comment: Welcome. Please add your code as code block, with three backticks here. Or per GitHub Gist Link. So we can help you.

Answer (score 5):

Most probably: the `gd` PHP extension is loaded / added more than once in your `php.ini` file (or in one of the additional `.ini` files that are loaded by PHP).

You can use `php --ini | grep gd` to find extra ini files for the module and check the php.ini file if it has `extension=gd.so`. As a solution, you can comment the later in the php.ini or delete the file(s) show in the first command.